# How to fill data into ejs view and return a string is pure html with expressjs

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I have a ejs view like this

```
<p>
<%= user.firstName %> <%= user.lastName %>
</p>
```

and in my controller I want to do something like this

```
var html = fill('ejs-template', data);
res.send(JSON.stringify(html))
```

then I can use the html with data content to do something else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quickest way, since you're using Express:

```
res.render('ejs-template', data, function(err, html) {
  if (err) return res.sendStatus(500);
  ...do something with the HTML...
});
```

If you don't necessarily want to use Express, you can use the `ejs` module directly:

```
var ejs = require('ejs');
ejs.renderFile('./views/ejs-template.ejs', data, options, function(err, html) {
  ...
});
```

More info [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ejs#usage).